# Delete bookmarks after seleting on ListBox (VBA Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Use case: I have a userform in excel that have ListBox1, ListBox2, Add Button, Undo Button, Cancel Button and Confirm Button. The ListBox1 should be populated with all the bookmarks that the document have and the user can click on the bookmark and then select Add button and the selected bookmark will disapear on ListBox1 and appear on ListBox2.

The issue is when the user clicks on Confirm Button the bookmarks that still listed on ListBox1 should be deleted on the word file. And is not happening.

Can someone help?

```
Private Sub Finish_Click()
    
    ' Declare variables
    Dim bookmarkName As String
    Dim i As Long ' Declare i as Long to avoid integer overflow
    Dim wdApp As Object ' Declare the Word application object
    Dim wdDoc As Object ' Declare the Word document object
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    ' Set the Word application and document objects
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument
    
    ' Loop through each item in ListBox1 and replace the empty spaces with underscores in the bookmark name
    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        bookmarkName = Replace(Me.ListBox1.List(i), " ", "_")
        Me.ListBox1.List(i) = bookmarkName ' Update the item in the ListBox
        If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists(bookmarkName) Then
            wdDoc.Bookmarks(bookmarkName).Range.Text.Delete
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Save and close the Word document
    wdDoc.Save
    wdDoc.Close
    
    ' Close the Word application
    wdApp.Quit
    
    ' Close the Userform
    Unload Me
    
    ' Call the ReplaceWordsBetweenAngleBrackets procedure
    Call ReplaceWordsBetweenAngleBrackets
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    ' Handle errors
    MsgBox "An error has occurred: " & Err.Description
    Resume Next ' Skip the line that caused the error and continue with the next line
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim bm As Object
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    ' Try to get an existing instance of Word, or create a new instance if none is found
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    ' Open the specified Word document
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Temp.print\wordTemplate.docx")
    
    ' Populate the ListBox with the bookmarks
    For Each bm In wdDoc.Bookmarks
        If Left(bm.Name, 4) <> "logo" And Left(bm.Name, 6) <> "footer" Then
            Me.ListBox1.AddItem Replace(bm.Name, "_", " ")
        End If
    Next bm
    
    ' Set a flag indicating whether the Word application was created in this routine
    wdAppCreated = (Err.Number <> 0)
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error has occurred: " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

I was expecting to bookmarks listed on ListBox1 be deleted on the word file, and also including the space where the bookmark were placed.

Comment: just an observation, if the original bookmark name contains spaces ,, this routine will fail as the will incorrectly converted to undercores when getting the names from listbox1 and they will no be found in the bookmars object.

Comment: The original bookmarks have underscores. I take it and then inserted in order to found them in word file